# Access cursor columns dynamically by index similar to array

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this js code that I need to convert into PL SQL. Below I've also included my own version of PL SQL conversion of this code but it has some errors. Any help on this is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Original JavaScript Code

```
for (var i=2; i<nsArray.length; i++) {
     if (weight<nsArray[i]) {

      whLowerLimit = nsArray[i-1];
      whUpperLimit = nsArray[i];

         }
       }
```

This is what I have done so far

```
Create Procedure

V_CUR_NSLOOKUP SYS_REFCURSOR;
V_NSLOOKUP MRWTHTPCT%ROWTYPE;

V_HEIGHT number;
V_WHLOWERLIMIT number;
V_WHUPPERLIMIT number;

Begin

    FOR I IN 3..V_NSLOOKUP.COUNT 
       LOOP
           IF V_WEIGHT < V_NSLOOKUP.(COLUMN_NAME) THEN 
              V_WHLOWERLIMIT := V_NSLOOKUP(COLUMN_NAME - 1);
              V_WHUPPERLIMIT := V_NSLOOKUP(COLUMN_NAME);

      END IF
     END LOOP; 
END
```

Comment: No way how to do that easily. Oracle table is not  two dimensional array. But maybe you can store a VARARAY as a single "column" in Oracle table. But beware you must know the max length of array before creating the table. See: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/VARRAY

Comment: what does this column name specifies , as it should be like this IF V_WEIGHT < V_NSLOOKUP.(i) THEN

Comment: Btw: why are you using imperative PL/SQL? This can be rewritten into single SQL statement - if you transpose the table (turn rows into columns). Do you really do not care how many times "whLowerLimit" was changed? So you are search for the last one row where "weight<nsArray[i]"

Comment: hi ashish, i've already updated the code.

Comment: hi ivan, we're porting this codes into pl sql and this is just a tiny portion of this code and right now am stuck in this part.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of doing that is storing the column names in a separate array. You can get the column names of a table through the all_tab_columns view:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE columns_names IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50);
  v_columns columns_names;
BEGIN
  SELECT column_name
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_columns
  FROM all_tab_columns 
  WHERE table_name = 'TABLE_NAME';

  -- Do your stuff...  

END;
```

Comment: thanks for answering pablomatico, i'll try ur solution